# Destroying resources once a branch is merged using terraform

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to automate creating and destroying resources per branch using gitlab runner

The current setup is as follows:
A terraform state file is used per branch and the state file is saved inside the runner instance.
when creating a branch a new tfvar is created for the branch with the branch name.
currently we are trying to automate the destroy step once a branch is merged into dev.
After researching this approach we understand that once a branch is merged the whole environment is destroyed and we cannot run the pipeline for this branch to destroy resources for this branch. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Between jobs everything is cleaned up.
You've written `file is save inside the runner instance` - do you store it somehow? If not, then it is created by terraform in .terraform directory, and then it's wiped out. You won't be able to remove it.

If so - you have to store state file remotely.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood right,you want to delete Terraform resources once a branch is merged.

here are some advices that might help you:

store the state file in remote place first, and it's recommended to have versions of it
(like AWS S3 versioning feature)

read more about backend configuration [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration).

use Terraform workspaces per each environment; for example, delete resources x in workspace pre-dev once it's a triggered pipeline runs to run TF commands when a branch merged to dev.

refer to documentation of workspaces [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces).